# jquery and pagination issue how to display more items

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am able to show all my images within my paginated jquery but I need it to display 9.

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $("#left").jPaginate();                         
    });  
    </script>
```

It is nly showing 4 for some reason....I have not set a number to show.

so I have updated the code:

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $("#left").jPaginate();                         

    }); 
    var number_of_items = obj.children().size();

//my code
if(number_of_items==0){
number_of_items = 1
}
</script>
```

So I am unable to show 9 but showing the number of items with the paginate() as it kills the script...

Comment: You can set the options for the plugins `jPaginate({ ... })` as specified in the version you have. [reference here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/17/jpaginate-a-fancy-jquery-pagination-plugin/)

Comment: @TimWax That worked! It is very glitchy.....seems to be it throws it when you go from start to finish and back again scrolling through.

Comment: <script src="http://c.fzilla.com/1286136086-jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://c.fzilla.com/1291523190-jpaginate.js"></script>

These seem to causing issues - im not sure they are clashing with other Jquery libraries....How do I get around that...